# Sum up 2 values in Django views.py

Tags: python, django

I just wondering is it possible to sum up the total of B1 + B2 from my code below ?

e.g. B1 + B2 = total

views.py

```
b1 = Income1.objects.filter(Q(title='Salary')| Q(title='Bonus')).annotate(as_float=Cast('total_amount', FloatField())).aggregate(Sum('as_float'))
b2 = Income2.objects.filter(Q(title='Overtime')).annotate(as_float=Cast('total_amount', FloatField())).aggregate(Sum('as_float'))

context= {
    'b1':b1,
    'b2':b2 
}
```

html

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Details</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Salary and Bonus</td>
        <td>{{ b1.as_float__sum}}</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Overtime</td>
        <td>{{ b2.as_float__sum}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Total Amount</td>
        <td>{{ total.as_float__sum}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Really appreciate if you could help me on this.

Comment: Why don't you simply do b1.as_float__sum + b2.as_float__sum ?

Comment: You mean do this in the html or in the views.py ?

Comment: You can in any place you like. in views or in HTML.

Comment: When I try  to do it in html it gives me "Could not parse the remainder: ' + b2.as_float__sum' from 'b1.as_float__sum + b2.as_float__sum'" while in views I got "'dict' object has no attribute 'as_float__sum'"